# Price increment and decrement according to days in datetime

Tags: c#, algorithm, datetime

I am writing a simple code for rental price calculation. My code should work like this (theoretically):

Base price = 300 (It is for 7 days)
and when user increases days from 7 to for e.g 10 the price increases and when they decrease again from 10 to 8 the price decrease.

I am doing it with date time component in C# windows form

**My Code:**

```
int baseprice = Convert.ToInt32(label21.Text);
int price = days * baseprice* 0.3;
if (days >= 7)
{

    int totalprice = baseprice + price;
    label21.Text = Convert.ToString(totalprice);
}
```

This code is working but it is always increasing not decreasing it when the days got decreased

Comment: You need to calculate number of days greater than 7 and then multiply that by base price.

Comment: I would suggest keeping the base price and final price as separate pieces of information - otherwise when the user changes something, you have to "undo" previous computation in order to work out the base price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would try to use  decimal type instead of integer.

Secondly, try to approach the logic differently. Try to caclulate price based on number of additional days. The code bellow is not ready, it needs a variable taken from UserInput.

```
int baseprice = Convert.ToInt32(label21.Text);

        decimal unit_cost= baseprice/7;
        decimal price = days *unit_cost;       
        int additional_days =  3; // use some variable input from user so it would be dynamic

            if (days >= 7)
            {

                int totalprice = baseprice + unit_cost * additonal_days
                label21.Text = Convert.ToString(totalprice);
            }
```

Comment: You were right i have to change my logic. which i have changed in a way that price directly get calculated with days and it works.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do this?

```
int price = days * baseprice * 0.3;
int totalprice = baseprice + (days >= 7 ? price : 0);
label21.Text = totalprice.ToString();
```

or this?

```
int totalprice = (int)(days * baseprice / 7f);
label21.Text = totalprice.ToString();
```